# Extract value from key-value pair of dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I have a CSV file with column name (in first row) and values (rest of the row). I wanted to create variables to store these values for every row in a loop. So I started off by creating a dictionary with the CSV file and I got a list of the records with a key-value pair. So now I wanted to create variables to store the "value" extracted from the "key" of each item and within a loop for every record. I am not sure if I am setting this correctly.

Here is the dictionary I have.

```
my_dict = [{'value id':'value1', 'name':'name1','info':'info1'},
           {'value id':'value2', 'name':'name2','info':'info2'},
           {'value id':'value3', 'name':'name3','info':'info3'},
          }]

for i in len(my_dict):
    item[value id] = value1
    item[name] = name1
    item[info] = info1
```

The `value id` and `name` will be unique and are identifiers the list. Ultimately, I wanted to create an `item` object i.e. `item[info] = info1` and I can add other codes to modify the `item[info]`.

Comment: what's the desired structure of your output? that simple for loop will overwrite the variables on each pass, not to mention the loop is not correct either

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: I want to create variables for each of the key in the Python Dictionary.

Comment: In your code `my_dict` is not a `dict`, it's a `list` of them. Also, you can only index `list`s with integer indices, so using `item[value id]` isn't going to work. Even if `my_dict` **was** a `dict`, it still wouldn't work because `value id` isn't a valid variable name — although `"value id"` would be a valid string constant and usable as a dictionary key if you had one.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
my_dict = [{'value':'value1', 'name':'name1','info':'info1'},
           {'value':'value2', 'name':'name2','info':'info2'},
           {'value':'value3', 'name':'name3','info':'info3'}]



for obj in my_dict:
    value = obj['value']
    name = obj['name']
    info = obj['info']
```

to expand on @aws_apprentice's point, you can capture the data by creating some additional variables

```
my_dict = [{'value':'value1', 'name':'name1','info':'info1'},
           {'value':'value2', 'name':'name2','info':'info2'},
           {'value':'value3', 'name':'name3','info':'info3'}]


values = []
names = []
info = []
for obj in my_dict:
    values.append(obj['value'])
    names.append(obj['name'])
    info.append(obj['info'])
```

Comment: this is pointless though, since each loop will overwrite the previous loops variables

Comment: OP didnt mention what they wanted to do with the data, i'm assuming they'll do some work in side loop